# How to improve performance of a query with an IN subquery

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

Get the count of other users having the *x* tag with `order_id` in `order_id` of users having the *y* tag

**table**: `MyCustomTable` (200K rows)

- `order_id`
- `user_id`
- `type` (`'x'` and `'y'`) my custom tags

and the query:

```
SELECT   COUNT(order_id),user_id
FROM     MyCustomTable
WHERE    type='x'
AND      order_id IN (SELECT order_id
                      FROM   MyCustomTable
                      WHERE  type   ='y'
                      AND    user_id='56')
AND      user_id <> '56'
GROUP BY user_id
```

**Create table output**

```
CREATE TABLE `MyCustomTable` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `type` enum('x','y') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'x',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `customeKey` (`user_id`,`type`,`order_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=360806 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Edit the question and add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE MyCustomTable;`

Comment: You are talking about counting users but your query appears to be counting orders *per* user. And it looks like it's the orders that are tagged, not the users. Can you make this part a little clearer?

Comment: Use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) to get the query execution plan and add that to your question.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to try with `IN` is to change it to `EXISTS` (with the proper modifications to the subquery):

```
SELECT   COUNT(order_id), user_id
FROM     MyCustomTable a
WHERE    type='x'
AND      EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM   MyCustomTable b
                      WHERE  type   ='y'
                      AND    user_id='56'
                      AND    a.order_id = b.order_id)
AND      user_id <> '56'
GROUP BY user_id
```

Another one is to get rid of the subquery:

```
SELECT   COUNT(distinct a.order_id), a.user_id
FROM     MyCustomTable a
JOIN     MyCustomTable b
             ON a.order_id = b.order_id
WHERE    a.type='x'
AND      b.type='y'
AND      a.user_id <> '56'
AND      b.user_id = '56'
GROUP BY a.user_id
```

Test them and use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) to check the plans used to execute them. Your question does not show indexes in that table, for fast execution some indexes will be needed - a multicolumn index on `(type, user_id, order_id)` covers both the main query and the subquery for the first case (and the same for your original query with `IN`) and works for the second case too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(UserID) as CountUsers
FROM
(SELECT 
    A.user_id as UserIDs, 
    A.order_id as XTag,
    B.order_id as YTag
FROM     MyCustomTable A
INNER JOIN MyCustomTable B 
    ON A.User_ID = B.User_ID 
    AND A.Order_ID <> B.Order_ID
WHERE A.type='x' 
    AND b.type = 'y'
    AND user_id <> '56') A
```

Would this work?

Comment: Please add an explanation as to how your answer helps the OP and answers their question. This will ensure future users benefit from your answer!